# XNA loading/splash screen on game start

Tags: xna

I'm trying to have a loading screen that pops up as soon as you run that executable that launches the game, whilst the game loads I want to display an image on the desktop much like how Gamemaker allows you to have a loading image.

I've had a brief look around and most people want an image to be shown whilst they load content which is not what I want, or perhaps it is... =P

My guess would be to set the game window borderless at the start, load the splash screen, draw it, then begin all the main loading (Specifically loading DirectInput through SlimDX takes a while). However would this support having a transparent/irregular shaped image? E.G if I wanted a borderless circle to be displayed whilst the game loads, would that be possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need it in XNA? You could use something else to make this window,, before starting your XNA game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you essentially want to have a window opened that is not full screen that also lacks the regular border and buttons that accompanies a window.

I can't test this but this should be a good start.

[Here!](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/65209/399049.aspx)

I would start by creating a bare bones Game1 class that can track an image and keep track of time for a timer.
Later you could add logic that actually tracks the loading of assets in the main program. 
To start I'd just test it for a fixed time like 3 seconds.

Comment: Sorry for the late response - maybe what I want isn't possible as this would cause 2 windows to be on the task bar I think

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't just do as the guy asking the question did in my link and have on initialization the window show up as a border-less rectangle with your logo or what not and when a timer/initial loading is done just return the window parameters to normal whether that be full screen, fixed screen resolution, etc.

Comment: Just to add to that thought.  It really comes down to the manipulation of the windows and not so much XNA itself (it just loads and displays your image).  You might be better served searching for or asking a question relating to the manipulation of win32 systems.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Just implement `System.Threading` and you're done.

Here's how it works, first add:

```
using System.Threading;
```

to the top of your class, then add the following things:

```
    //the enum for state types
    enum GameState
    {
        Loading,
        StartMenu

    }

    //Init our gameState enum as variable
    GameState gameState;        

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        gameState = GameState.Loading; 


        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        device = GraphicsDevice;

        Window.Title = "Your Window";

        //Other stuff that you had here before, now go in LoadGame()

        loadingscreen = Content.Load<Texture2D>("loading");             

        Thread bgLoad = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoadGame));
        bgLoad.IsBackground = true;
        bgLoad.Start();

    }
    public void LoadGame()
    {
        //Loading stuff here


        gameState = GameState.StartMenu; //or GameState.Playing
    }
```

and then put a loading texture in your Content Project